# When to use algo vs. algunos to say "some"

Tags: uso-de-palabras

I am trying to understand the use of algo vs. algunos in the sentences below.  At first I thought algo was a pronoun, and algunos was an adjective.  But in the third sentence, Algunas appears to be a pronoun.

Él tiene algo de torta.   He has some cake.
Él tiene algunos libros.  He has some apples

Algunas de las pelotas son amarillas.  Some of the balls are yellow.

I reviewed some of the previous questions, but didn't see the answer to my question.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Algo` is the singular form of `algunos`.

Since there is only one cake (or piece of cake), you use algo for the cake...

> El tiene algo de torta

If you have some pieces of cake, then you have this

> El tiene algunos pedazos de torta

since there are several pieces of cake, you use algunos.

Comment: I would say "algo" is fur uncountable nouns. The singular form of "algunos" is "algún", as in "Creo que tengo algún teléfono viejo que funciona".